# How to read Arabic character in ASP.Net that is stored in VARCHAR field

Tags: asp.net, database, utf-8, arabic, varchar

In my database there is a field which stores Arabic names. Field type is `VARCHAR`.

When I run `SELECT` statement in SQL Editor to get records then it shows me value **ãÇ äÇá** which is actually **ما نال**

Problem is when I am displaying this value in ASP.Net, it is displayed as **ÒÃ õÃß**. I have changed page encoding to UTF-8 but no luck. How do I display Arabic names properly in ASP.Net that are stored in `VARCHAR` field? Please note field type cannot be changed in database.

Comment: If the database has the proper collation, you should be getting the proper value in the string - check that. As for the page output, you'll find that it's quite tricky to ensure that it's *actually* in UTF-8 - some of the issues occur on the ASP.NET side, some in your code, some on the browser side. Does `yourInputString.ToCharArray().Select(i => (int)i)` produce the expected code points (e.g. `1605, 1575, 32, 1606, 1575, 1604`)?

Comment: Yes I am getting points 201, 195, 32, 245, 195, 223.

Comment: Okay, that's bad. That means you don't actually have the unicode characters - your database/table/column collation is wrong. This means that you'll have to either fix the collation, or find the proper encoding to re-encode the C# string.

Comment: Ok I changed column type to NVARCHAR but same issue. What to do now?

Comment: Your data is already botched, so `nvarchar` doesn't save you - it's too late for that, basically. Do you have a way of exporting the data in the proper encoding and then converting them to their proper `nvarchar` representation?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1256">` to your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Use

> KeepOrgMultibyte=1

in Sybase connection string in web.config. Example given below.

```
<add name="Sybase" connectionString="Data Source='192.168.0.70';Port=9100;UID='myuser';PWD='mypassword';Database='mydatabase';KeepOrgMultibyte=1;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your collation is wrong - you're storing arabic-collated data in a non-arabic-collated `varchar` column.

However, you should be able to force the correct collation just for the `select` by using the `collate` keyword. A quick sample:

```
select [Text] collate Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS from YourTable;
```

If this doesn't help, the data has already been inserted incorrectly in the table. That's a bit of a problem.

First, you have to find the proper mis-encodings that lead to where you are now. The problem is, it's pretty likely you're actually dealing with a MS SQL-specific encoding, which probably will not be easy to handle in .NET.

Comment: I am actually using Sybase.

Comment: @FrankMartin How close that is to MS SQL depends mostly on the version :D What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 22774 :)

Comment: I created a new table with NVARCHAR field type, entered one Arabic name and it has same issue.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database from .NET? The ODBC driver?

Comment: No I am using "Adaptive Server Enterprise Managed Provider" (Sybase.Data.AseClient)

Comment: @FrankMartin I can't really help you much, I don't have any environment to test this. Have you used a unicode literal to enter the name (`N'ما نال'` on MS SQL)? Could it be that the application you're editing handles the encoding wrong? I couldn't find any encoding that would encode your string the way you're suggesting... how are you filling the database in the first place?

Comment: Found the solution. Use "KeepOrgMultibyte=1" in Sybase connection string in web.config.